# MySQL update null field using value from nearby date

Tags: mysql

I have a table keyed with date/person which has two value columns (val1, val2). In most cases they are both filled. However, there are some cases (which need fixing) where one of them is filled, and the other is null. These cases typically occur in pairs, one day apart. For each person, no two pairs will be within a month of each other.

I have selected all dates which fall within 3 days of another entry (to account for weekends) for a given person using the following query:

```
SELECT distinct t1.* from mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.person = t2.person and t1.date <> t2.date 
WHERE abs(datediff(t1.date,t2.date))<= 3
```

This returns:

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| date       | person     | val1  | val2  |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| 2009-10-26 | A          |  null |    62 |
| 2009-10-27 | A          |     4 |  null |
| 2010-01-02 | A          |     2 |  null |
| 2010-01-04 | A          |  null |   101 |
| 2010-01-04 | B          |  null |    -4 |
| 2010-01-06 | B          |     3 |  null |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

Now what I'd like to do (and this is where I'm stuck), is to update the null value for the earlier date of each pair using the missing value taken from the other, to create something like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| date       | person     | val1  | val2  |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| 2009-10-26 | A          |    *4 |    62 |
| 2009-10-27 | A          |     4 |  null |
| 2010-01-02 | A          |     2 |  *101 |
| 2010-01-04 | A          |  null |   101 |
| 2010-01-04 | B          |    *3 |    -4 |
| 2010-01-06 | B          |     3 |  null |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With some scripting (Perl, PHP) that'd be easy...